# How to give CRL to openssl s_client?

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509

I'm testing certificate revocation with a test server. I'm trying to use `openssl s_client` with *crl_check* parameter for testing the revocation. I have appended ca certs to a chain file I give in *CAfile* parameter.

With the command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -crl_check -cert cert.pem \
-key key.pem -CAfile ca_chain.pem -state -verify_return_error debug
```

I get a response:

```
Verify return code: 3 (unable to get certificate CRL)
```

Which is natural because I don't give the CRL.

**How should I give the CRL** (where the server cert is revoked) **to the openssl s_client** to get certificate revocation checked in negotiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 1.02 you should be able to do this. From the changelog:

```
*) New options -CRL and -CRLform for s_client and s_server for CRLs.
   [Steve Henson]
```

In versions before that the behavior is undocumented: [You have to include the CRL together with the certificate in the same file](https://superuser.com/questions/742231/s-client-not-failing-on-revoked-certifcate/742289#742289) if you are using a single file with `-CAfile`. If you are using a directory with `-CApath` instead  [it gets even harder](https://superuser.com/a/742305/291741).

Comment: Great, with -CAfile appending the crl in pem format to the ca chain file helped as the [link](http://superuser.com/questions/742231/s-client-not-failing-on-revoked-certifcate/742305#742305) you shared suggested.